# Disable access of a certain application to a certain driver

Tags: windows, drivers

Is there a way to disable access of certain application to a certain driver? This seems like a pretty useful feature but I do not know if Windows allows it.

The simplest example would be using it for testing purposes.

If this is possible I would love to know how can it be done. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications do not have access to drivers.  Only the operating system can communicate with drivers.  Applications make requests of the OS and the OS uses the driver to fulfill the request.